# Play framework 2.5 performance configuration

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am switching from play framework 2.3 to 2.5, but I experience very bad performances server side. Are there configuration settings needed to improve performances ? The symptoms are (with only one user):

- Computation time longer than expected (compared to the same computation in a junit test for example)
- 2 server requests that should run in parallel take a performance hit when requested at the same time (as if they were run in the same thread)

My configuration is the following:

- Play 2.5.10, Java build 1.8.0_111-b14, sbt 0.13.13
- Play dependencies: play-authenticate
- Default execution context / thread pool used

Any ideas why the performances are bad ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since play 2.4 introduced dependency injection, you may see a delay for the first request. This is because play needs some time to create injected objects the first time they were requested. Other than that, your question is basically impossible to answer. What do you mean by "very bad" performances? How did you measure?

Comment: I have a created a GET request to test that. The request takes between 1900 and 2100 ms server side (because of a computation). Then I target the server twice very quickly. The response time for each request is around 3000ms. This runs on a macbook pro so it should be able to handle both requests in parallel and return each of them in 2000 ms, no ?

Comment: As I said, it's almost impossible to track down the problem here, as there are many unknown variables. First of all, get meaningful numbers. For example write an integration test for the relevant controller function and run it sequentially 100 times. Then take the average duration and compare it to those of your play 2.3 version. Do the same again, but this time run several requests in parallel. If you can see a significant difference between play 2.5 and 2.3, then there might something be wrong. If not, you are probably fine.